# How do I render a button inside the react-native-maps pop-up box?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to render a button which I can use to redirect to another page within the description page (the pop-up-box if you select a marker) using **AirBnb maps** (using `MapView.Markers`). I am not sure how to achieve this.

Currently my markers look as follow:

```
const markers = [{
  longitude: 8.545592,
  latitude: 47.366465,
  description: "Bike 1",
  title: "Bike 1"
},
{
  longitude: 8.545892,
  latitude: 47.366365,
  description: "Bike 2",
  title: "Bike 2"
}
];
```

Whenever I try to input JSX into a text, I get a `NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to NSString` error. (When I do this:

```
const markers = [{
  longitude: 8.545592,
  latitude: 47.366465,
  description: <Text>Bike1</Text>, //"Bike 1", //<Text> Bike1 </Text>
  title: "Bike 1"
},
{
  longitude: 8.545892,
  latitude: 47.366365,
  description: "Bike 2",
  title: "Bike 2"
}
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more than just text, what you should do is define a custom [Callout](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/callout.md) instead of using `description` prop. For example:

```
<MapView.Marker
  coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
  title={marker.title}
>
  <MapView.Callout>
    <View style={styles.callout}>
      <Button title='Click Me!' onPress={() => console.log('Clicked')} />
    </View>
  </MapView.Callout>
</MapView.Marker>
```