# Display a button inside the mapview marker?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm currently developing a react native app using the airbnb map module.

My map contains several markers on which I can click to open a `MapView` component. It contains a title and a description.

I would like to add a button to this `MapView`, however [the solution that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475332/react-native-airbnb-maps-how-do-i-render-a-button-inside-the-airbnb-maps-pop-up) is not working. I customize it like that (this is the `return` part from my googlemap component:

```
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>

    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      customMapStyle={mapStyle}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 48.852968,
        longitude: 2.349902,
        latitudeDelta: 0.1,
        longitudeDelta: 0.1
      }}
    >
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{
          latitude: 48.852968,
          longitude: 2.349902
        }}
          title={ 'myTitle' }
          description={ 'myDescription' }
          pinColor={ 'blue' }
          onCalloutPress={() => alert('Clicked')}
      >
        <MapView.Callout>
          <View>
            <Text>Click Me!</Text>
          </View>
        </MapView.Callout>
      </MapView.Marker>

    </MapView>

  </View>
);
```

What I want:
1- Display my blue marker on the map (using lat and lng)
2- Click on the marker
3- Have a little popup with title, description, and 'Click me!' button
4- Get 'Clicked' as a `console.log`

What happens instead:
1- Display my blue marker on the map (using lat and lng)
2- Click on the marker
3- Have a little popup 'Click me!' button (more as a blue link but I don't know how it's supposed to render)
4- No 'Clicked' in my console

Has this feature been deprecated? Or am I doing something wrong? I followed the solution and the documentation but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Check discussion here : https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/521

Answer (score 5):

**Remove onPress from your button and add it to the Marker(See after pincolor), try clicking on the button again.**

```
<MapView.Marker
    coordinate={{
        latitude: myLat,
        longitude: myLng
    }}
    title={ 'myTitle' }
    description={ 'myDescription' }
    pinColor={ 'blue' }
    onCalloutPress={() => alert('Clicked')}
>
    <MapView.Callout>
        <View>
            <Text>Click Me!</Text>
        </View>
    </MapView.Callout>
</MapView.Marker>
```

This is working for me. Hope this will help you too :)

Comment: Mmh doesn't seem to be working as it says the `onPress` prop is required in `Button`! How did you bypass that?

Comment: Updated answer, just check again and you can style text element like a button.

Comment: Thanks! But I still have nothing in my `console.log`, and my `title` and `description` are not displayed in my `Marker`... You're saying it's working well on your side?

Comment: isn't it firing an alert on click of it?

Comment: No I got nothing!

Comment: have you copied my same code into your file ? As it working fine in my app. Also update your question with more code so i'll try to find out any other issue from code if there is.

Comment: Done, added the whole `return` part from my googlemap component. I think nothing else would be useful as I already tried it within a loop (with several hardcoded data from an array) and nothing else is happening

Comment: what if i have two buttons in one Callout? `onCalloutPress` doesn't work for each particular one

Answer (score 0):

apply **zIndex** to your button it will show on your mapview